# how to setting drupal i18n translation module not to translate system menu I don't want?

Tags: i18n-l10n

In my site I am using drupal7 i18n module to translate to Burmese language. But my problem is I don't like drupal to translate system fields that does not need to translate because translation is totally wrong and might confuse for user, so it is better for user to leave these as English such as system field and something like that. When I click Burmese language in language switcher block, all for content fields, sitemap navigation, content types fields and product fields are changed to burmese, but translation is really really confusing for me and also for customer. So I am thinking that it is easy for me and customer if not system translated, and I will have to manually interpret the fields and taxonomy that I want to local user to understand.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Highlights in above two images are really misunderstanding and that doesn't need for i18n module to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Administration Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language) module.

> This module lets the administrator see all administration pages in her preferred language.
>
> You can use this to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).
>
> You can use the standard Languages page to choose the language of the admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to keep translation applying everywhere, assumed you review all confusing translations and replace them by ones of your own.

You can do this at the `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` page of your site.

The only issue with that solution is it might regard a too wide number of strings, so being a huge work.